# Add users to System.Activities.DurableInstancing roles

Tags: .net, sql-server, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

We have a lot of customers who connects to the sql server using db_datawriter and db_datareader roles
We had no flexible roles defined until now.

Now our software uses newly the worklfow foundataion persistence store.
To enable it like described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee395773(v=vs.100).aspx) we used the SQL scripts SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreSchema.sql and SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreLogic.sql, which creates a new db schema `System.Activities.DurableInstancing` and 3 new roles within:

- `System.Activities.DurableInstancing.InstanceStoreObservers`
- `System.Activities.DurableInstancing.InstanceStoreUsers`
- `System.Activities.DurableInstancing.WorkflowActivationUsers`

Users with `db_datawriter` and `db_datawriter` roles only get SqlException:

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'CreateLockOwner',
>   database 'mydatabase', schema 'System.Activities.DurableInstancing'.

It occurs in the store.Execute, if the software starts:

```
InstanceHandle handle = store.CreateInstanceHandle();
var createOwnerCommand = new CreateWorkflowOwnerCommand
{
    InstanceOwnerMetadata =
    {
        { XNWorkflowHostTypePropertyName, new InstanceValue(XNWorkflowHostTypeIdentifierName) }
    }
};
InstanceView view = store.Execute(handle, createOwnerCommand, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

I have already tried this:

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'System.Activities.DurableInstancing.InstanceStoreObservers' , @membername ='db_datawriter';
EXEC sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'System.Activities.DurableInstancing.InstanceStoreUsers' , @membername ='db_datawriter';
EXEC sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'System.Activities.DurableInstancing.WorkflowActivationUsers', @membername ='db_datawriter';
```

with an error message: Error 15405: Cannot use the special principal 'db_datawriter'.

**Qquestion:**

Is there any other possibility that I overlook to grant permissions to this roles with a script, without to know the login names etc.?

Answer (score 0):

In general you don't grant users access rights to the persistence store.
Users of your application use the persistence store through the workflow engine and the engine has access to the store.

Is there a particular scenario where you require them to access the store directly?

Comment: I have just added a code causing the `SqlException`. Users should be allowed at least to view or start already persisted workflows. Their program function rights are managed independent of DB permissions. How can it be made otherwise?

Comment: Viewing and starting already persisted workflows is done either through AppFabric (if that is how you are hosting the workflows) or through the application.  Users do not require personnel access to the database.  There is nothing they can do there anyway.  The applications access the database for the users using credentials supplied by the application (usualy in app or web config)

Comment: Yes, our application access the DB using credentials, which is insufficient to execute `CreateWorkflowOwnerCommand` and initialize instance store. So I have no other way than to fix this credentials? I would like to avoid this because of customer support overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a problem similar to yours by taking advantage of part of your solution, making this small change:

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'System.Activities.DurableInstancing.InstanceStoreObservers' ,'myUser'
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'System.Activities.DurableInstancing.InstanceStoreUsers' ,'myUser'
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'System.Activities.DurableInstancing.WorkflowActivationUsers' ,'myUser'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).